# What is the difference between lroundf(), floor() and nearbyintf()?

Tags: c

I am aware that the above mentioned are used to round off the float values and double values. But can someone please explain how each one rounds off the values? I couldn't find any documentation for this.

Comment: IMHO, this question should really be tagged as "C" and not "iphone" or "objective-c".

Comment: So how could you "not find any documentation" if the Linux standard (RedHat), Oracle, the C standards (ISO and GNU), and the C header files document them?

Comment: U were right. As an iPhone developer, i was basically searching for the documentation in iPhone SDK and coudln't find any documentation on this regard. Now i get to understand that these concepts point to C. Thanks again

Comment: Using the function lroundf to round the decimal number to the nearest whole num

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the manual pages (learn to Google for "man WHATEVER" when WHATEVER is a library function):

- [`lroundf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lroundf) - round to nearest integer, away from zero
- [`floor()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/floor) - largest integral value not greater than argument
- [`nearbyintf()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/nearbyintf/) - round to integral value in floating-point format

Comment: `lroundf` rounds ties away from zero, not all values away from zero.

Comment: `nearbyintf` uses the current rounding mode.